# FFT on non-rectangular part of image

Tags: computer-vision, fft

I need to do a FFT on an image for noise reduction, but the problem is that I do not need the complete image, but only a circle in the middle. The borders are a fixed rig, thus I am not interested in what it displays, but it has an impact on the result of the FFT.

Is there any way to just cut out a circular part and use that for the FFT? Note that if I use black 
background, the edge between background, and image data will have quite an impact.

Comment: I bet you'll have answers by asking on [dsp.se]

Comment: ah, thanks for the link. Will check it out ;)

Comment: Why not just do noise reduction on the entire image and then mask the filtered result and the original image to only include the circular filtered portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on signal processing (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/fft-on-non-rectangular-part-of-image).